# How to prove that lattice width is attained?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, integer-programming, integer-lattices

Let $K \subseteq R^n$ be a convex body, that is, a closed bounded convex set. Given a vector $d \in R^n$ we define the width of $K$ along $d$ to be:
$w_d(K) = \underset{x \in K}{max} \space d^tx - \underset{x \in K}{min}  \space d^tx$

The *lattice width* of $K$ is defined as the minimum width along any **integral** vector $d$, that is
$w(K) = \underset{d \in Z^n}{min} \space w_d(K)$

How can we prove that this minimum is always attained when $K$ is full dimensional (i.e. the width of the lattice is bounded)?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you prove that $w_d(K)$ is continuous as a function of $d$? Can you restrict '$d \in \mathbb{Z}^n$' some bounded set?

Comment: $d$ is given. The explanation can not be changed.

Comment: On second thought, why isn't the minimum value simply attained at $d = 0$?

Comment: Nope, I don't think you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is mostly in Proposition 2.3. of:

Draisma, J., McAllister, T. B., & Nill, B. (2012). Lattice-Width Directions and Minkowski's 3rd-Theorem. SIAM Journal on Discrete Mathematics, 26(3), 1104-1107.